# Fastest key-value store for random disk reads?

Tags: performance, nosql

I want a key-value store, with records stored on disk. (There are too many for memory.) I want to use a single machine.

What key-value store will provide the fastest random reads (off disk)?

Answer (score 3):

Without context, this is a poor question.

Bound to a single machine your requirement is a function of IO performance, not platform. An Access mdb file on a [FusionIO](http://www.fusionio.com/platforms/iodrive-octal/) card could outperform [Trinity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trinity/) on a 5400rpm drive in a narrow band of tests.

You'll have to be more specific if you want answers of any value.

Edit: following comment.

Context would be a description of what you're building. As I indicated, whichever k-v system you choose you will be IO bound when constrained to a single machine. On EC2 block storage the choice of k-v becomes even more irrelevant.

If you're building on EC2 look at the native products they already provide e.g. SimpleDB or Elasticache.

Comment: What additional context would you like? This will be a single EC2 machine, with 8GB of memory.